# What determines whether an interrupt is IO-APIC-edge or IO-APIC-level?

Tags: linux, hardware, interrupt, pci, x86

Looking at the contents of `/proc/interrupts` on an x86 Linux, I see that some of the interrupts are `IO-APIC-edge` while others are `IO-APIC-level`.

I wonder what determines the interrupt type, is it the interrupt generating device, the interrupt controller (APIC), the Linux kernel or the BIOS ?

(the reason I wonder is because I moved a PCI card from a dual processor Pentium III system, where it was recognized as `IO-APIC-level` to a dual processor Xeon system where it was recognized as `IO-APIC-edge`)

Answer (score 2):

For example the [82093AA IO-APIC](http://www.intel.com/design/chipsets/datashts/290566.htm) has I/O redirection table registers (IOREDTBL) which have a 
writeable bit specifying the **trigger mode** (which can be level or edge sensitive). These
registers seem to be reflected by `struct IO_APIC_route_entry` in the kernel source.

Digging a bit through the 2.6.18 kernel source, one comes across a function `setup_IO_APIC_irqs(..)` which loops over all IO-APICs found and over all IRQ lines for each IO-APIC and calls `io_apic_write(..)` to write to the APIC's registers.

The trigger type seems to be determined by the function `MPBIOS_trigger(..)` (called by `irq_trigger(..)`) which in turn seems to consult a variable `mp_irqs` which in turn seems to be filled in `arch/x86_64/kernel/mpparse.c`. This file seems to read the a the MP configuration table conforming to the [Intel MultiProcessor Specification](http://www.intel.com/design/pentium/datashts/242016.htm).

Qouting from this specification:

```
The BIOS constructs the MP configuration data structures, presenting the 
hardware in a known format to the standard device drivers or to the 
hardware abstraction layer of the operating system.
```

So I'd say the kernel configures the interrupt trigger type based on
information provided by the BIOS.

A side comment: the [Wikipedia article on Interrupts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt#Level-triggered) mentions that

```
The original PCI standard mandated shareable level-triggered interrupts.
```

(which seems to come from the fact that edge triggered interrupts sent by multiple devices at the same time on the same line will collide). So `IO-APIC-edge` is a bit unexpected for PCI devices.

Answer (score 1):

What determines this, is the variable `lpfc_use_msi`. If You set it on 2 in the `modprobe.conf` then it will use MSI instead of IO. It is recommended to use 'MSI interrupt mode'.